# ChangeNotifierProvider Not Being called

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, listener, provider

My ChangeNotifierProvider is not being called....

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyGlobals>(
        builder: (context) => MyGlobals(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: MyGlobals().GetTheme() == "dark" ? ThemeData(fontFamily: 'ERAS', primaryColor: Colors.black, accentColor: Colors.amberAccent, secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.black54):
          ThemeData(fontFamily: 'ERAS', primaryColor: Colors.white, accentColor: Colors.black, secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.white70),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        ));
  }
}
```

And this is MyGlobals:

```
String _theme = "dark";

class MyGlobals with ChangeNotifier {


  getTheme() => _theme;


  void setTheme(String _themecolor) {
    _theme = _themecolor;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Im not getting any errors its just not being called. I am calling setTheme from another .dart file and its not being changenotifierprovider is not being called. MyGlobals is a seperate .dart file from the ChangeNotifierProvider code above.

Comment: you need a Consumer to listen the changes

Comment: Can you please specify?

Comment: I mean, where are you calling `setTheme` method ? could you add your MyHomePage widget

Comment: No the MyGlobals class in located within a different .dart file. I want to keep it that way as well.

Comment: do you call `setTheme` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do call setTheme from another .dart file so im expecting the notifier to be triggered then. But its not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Consumer` widget to listen the changes you made in your `Model`, like this :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyGlobals>(
      builder: (context) => MyGlobals(),
      child: Consumer<MyGlobals>(
        builder: (_, model, __) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: model.getTheme() == "dark"
                ? ThemeData(
                    fontFamily: 'ERAS',
                    primaryColor: Colors.black,
                    accentColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                    secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.black54)
                : ThemeData(
                    fontFamily: 'ERAS',
                    primaryColor: Colors.white,
                    accentColor: Colors.black,
                    secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.white70),
            home: MyHomePage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then you can update your theme in this way:

```
Provider.of<MyGlobals>(context).setTheme("your_theme")
```

Comment: Sorry man still not working. Its just not being called when i call setTheme.

Comment: add the code when you call setTheme in your question and I will update my answer, I'm sure that you are creating a new object

Comment: That did it! Do i still need that consumer? Why do I need both the changenotifierprovider and consumer. What does that consumer do?

Comment: I recommend you to read the official doc : https://pub.dev/packages/provider  , Provider has two main actions "expose" and "read" values,  Using ChangeNotifierProvider you are exposing your `MyGlobals`, now every time you change/update your model , you can use `Consumer` to listen the changes.

Comment: sure, you are welcome, you can follow me on twitter :) same alias